# Angular Modal not binding to scope properties

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a model controller like such:

```
pcApp.controller("ModalInstanceController", function ($scope, $modalInstance, model) {

    $scope.claim = model;
    $scope.payNow = function () {
        $modalInstance.close("now");
    };
    $scope.refuse = function () {
        $modalInstance.close("later");
    };
    $scope.payLater = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss("cancel");
    };
});
```

The modal template is:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="newClaimPopup.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="desktop">PayCaddy Claim</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>{{claim.SenderFullName}} is claiming an amount of R{{claim.Amount}} for a golfing bet with him that you lost, with the message:</p>
        <br />
        <p>{{claim.Description}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="payNow()">Yes</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" ng-click="refuse()">Refuse</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="payLater()">Later</button>
    </div>
</script>
```

This is in a partial view included in `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
    <div id="claim-notice-template">
        @Html.Partial("_NewClaimPopupTemplate")
    </div>
```

I show the modal using this code:

```
$scope.showNewClaimPopup = function (viewModel) {
    $scope.claim = viewModel;
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
        templateUrl: "newClaimPopup.html",
        controller: "ModalInstanceController",
        size: "sm",
        resolve: {
            model: function () {
                return $scope.claim;
            }
        }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function () {
        debugger;
        $log.info("Modal accepted at: " + new Date());
    }, function () {
        $log.info("Modal dismissed at: " + new Date());
    });
};
```

The `viewModel` parameter passed in to `$scope.showNewClaimPopup` is valid and fully populated. The `resolve` option for `open` is also working, because in `ModalInstanceController` I can see that the `model` parameter is the same valid viewmodel. Yet when the modal displays, the binding templates are all blank.

All code shown is in one `MainController` assigned to a `div` that surrounds everything, including the partial containing the modal template.

Why is the template not binding as expected?

Comment: Anything in your console?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `$scope` to be used to compile modal template:

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    scope: $scope, // <--- this line is necessary
    animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
    templateUrl: "newClaimPopup.html",
    controller: "ModalInstanceController",
    size: "sm",
    resolve: {
        model: function () {
            return $scope.claim;
        }
    }
});
```

If you don't provide `scope` config then modal will create new child scope of the `$rootScope`, which obviously doesn't contain `claim` object.